# Stop JQuery Tools Tooltip from appearing on undefined title values

Tags: tooltip, jquery-tools

```
<input id="name" name="user[name]" size="30" title="Please enter a valid name." type="text" />
<input id="email" name="user[email]" size="30" type="text" />

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(':text').tooltip({
    events: {
      input: 'mouseover, mouseout'
    },
    opacity: 0.95,
    position: 'top center',
    effect: 'slide',
    tip: 'test.field-tip',
    onBeforeShow: function(args){
      if(this.getTrigger().data('title') == undefined)
        return true;
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

The tooltip should only appear the on *name* since it is the only field with a given *title*. That's how I'm trying to approach it, but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your selector to

```
$(":text[title]")
```